# Populate Html.DropDownList with jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I have:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#myDropDownLisTId").find('tbody')  
                .append($('<option>').attr('value', data[i].id).attr('name', data[i].name)
                );               
            }
```

But the dropdown list always remains the same. Why is this not working? the data variable has beautiful values.
Also, I would like before the for loop to empty the dropdown list/ How to do it?

Here is my drop down list in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("myDropDownLisTId")%>
```

Comment: what is data ? is that a json object ?

Comment: @Shyju Yes, I return return Json(List<TableInDatabase>);

Comment: @Shyju I added some details. Can you see the question again please?

Comment: @Shyju But how to empty the dropdown list before that?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, not an alternative to JavaScript. "jquery or JS" does not make sense.

Comment: @user1322207 - Please be sure to follow the guidelines in (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Marking answers to your questions as correct (appropriately of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$.each(data, function() {
   $("#myDropDownLisTId").append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.Text));
 });
```

Check my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073255/40521) for more details about how to get data from an MVC action to load the dropdown list

**EDIT:** As per the comment to remove existing data

```
$("#myDropDownLisTId").empty()
$.each(data, function() {
   $("#myDropDownLisTId").append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.Text));
 });
```

**EDIT 2:** 
[Idrumsgood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142929/idrumgood)'s answer has a very good point. Instead of calling the append method everytime inside the loop, just keep the value inside a variable and call the html method only once.

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

```
var items=""
$.each(data, function() {
   items+="<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.Text + "</option>";
 });
$("#myDropDownLisTId").html(items);
```

Comment: It's working :) But how to empty the dropdown list before that?

Comment: replace `append` with `html` :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine But now there is only one option tag in the dropdown list

Comment: @Shyju And how do I add a separator in the dropdownlist - that can not be selected? "------"

Comment: @user1322207: What is a separator ?

Comment: @Shyju Like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/SeparatorComboListBox/cssepcb3.jpg

the line

Comment: @user1322207: use a flag varibale and inside the loop set it from false to true,check the value of variable, if true, add that --- else add thh data from json

Answer (score 6):

Though the other answers will accomplish what you wish to do, I would recommend writing your option HTML to a string variable and appending it after the loop has finished, rather than appending within the loop. This can have some noticeable performance advantages when your list gets longer. Using `.html()` will also take care of emptying the list each time.

```
        var tempList = '';
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
            tempList += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '" name="' + data[i].name +'">' + data[i].text + '</option>';            
        }
        $("#myDropDownLisTId").html(tempList);
```

Comment: This is a very valid point. Thanks for sharing. I just added this to the accepted answer. +1 for teaching me something today.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ykFJd/2/

JS

```
var data = [
    {id:'0', name:'test 0'},  
    {id:'1', name:'test 1'},
    {id:'2', name:'test 2'},
    {id:'3', name:'test 3'},
    {id:'4', name:'test 4'},    
];


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $("#myDropDownLisTId").append(
        $('<option />', {
            'value': data[i].id,
            'name': data[i].name,
            'text': data[i].name
        })
    );               
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a nice function for binding a js hash to a select lists. See my answer at [Best way to populate select list with JQuery / Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995017/best-way-to-populate-select-list-with-jquery-json/9995132#9995132)

Example usage:

```
// you can easily pass in response.d from an AJAX call if it's JSON formatted
var users = [ {id: 1, name: 'Alice'}, {id: 2, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 3, name: 'Cindy'} ]
setSelectOptions($('#selectList'), users, 'id', 'name');
```